# BZip2 "selectorMtf value too big" error when decompressing

Tags: java, bzip2, apache-commons-compress

I'm getting error "Corrupted input, selectorMtf value too big" when trying to decompress the string compressed by bzip2.
Below is my decompress java code

```
private void decompress() throws IOException {
    InputStream fin = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("C:\\Comp.txt"));
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
    OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get("C:\\Dec.txt"));
    BZip2CompressorInputStream bzIn = new BZip2CompressorInputStream(in);
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[9];
    int n = 0;
    while (-1 != (n = bzIn.read(buffer))) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, n);
    }
    out.close();
    bzIn.close();
}
```

The error happens at this line

```
BZip2CompressorInputStream bzIn = new BZip2CompressorInputStream(in);
```

Anyone knows how to fix this error please ?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Commons Compress?

Comment: yes @Olivier, I'm using commons-compress-1.21